# Obtain value from an input in real time

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, express-handlebars, hbs

I am trying to get the value of an input in real time but I can't get it

I'm trying that in the bottom button the first **X** is the amount of carrots specified in the input above, and in the second **X** is a number that will be calculated in a *script*, all in real time (if the input number changes, the bottom ones will change automatically) but for that I need a way to get the value of the input in real time

Here's the code, I'm using `express-handlebars` and **Bootstrap** for the styles and classes

```html
<div class="col-md-auto mx-auto">
   <h3 class="text-center">Buy</h3>
   <form action="/dashboard/" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
         <input type="number" id="buyA" min="3"class="form-control" name="buyA" placeholder="Amount">
         <div class="d-grid gap-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Buy X Things X</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="buy" name="buy" value="buy">
   </form>
</div>
```

One of the scripts I've tried is this one, but it doesn't show anything and I just put it in place of the X (I'm a bit of a newbie in HTML), that is, instead of the X I just put that Script to hopefully get its value

```html
<script>
    let buyAmount = document.getElementById('buyFormAmount').value;
    if (!buyAmount || <= 0) = "?";
    return buyAmount;
</script>
```

Comment: "I've tried scripts and various things" - can you share some of them? we can try to work from there.

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran Sure, I just edited by adding one of the things I tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an Event Listener on the input field, see exemple below.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('txt');
x.addEventListener('input', function(){
    document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML="Buy "+x.value+" Rabbits by "+ x.value+" Carrots"
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" value="" >
<button id="myBtn" value="myvalue" >Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create function that will be called when input of id `buyForm` changes. In that function, you need to get the value of input, calculate 'the second **X**', and set inner html for `span` HTML elements that should be in your button of class `btn btn-success`.

Comment: Thank you, but it would be better if you could give a practical example, please